Emission spectrum of ATP and other biomolecules?
Beside causing excitation, laser can also stimulate emission of photons of chosen energy - e.g. in Rabi cycle, STED microscope ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STED_microscopy ), or ASE (amplified spontaneous emission).
So if e.g. ATP would have some emission spectrum, we could try to speedup its degradation with laser, for example for radiotherapy to starve the cancer ( https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.15399 ), or maybe of some toxic molecules, or try to inhibit some biochemical pathways by causing deexcitation of crucial molecules ...
However, I am not able to find information about emission spectrum of ATP - is it known?
Could it e.g. be calculated numerically or found experimentally?
Where to search for emission spectra of biomolecules?

ATP does fluoresce, you do not need huge laser intensity to make it do so or to induce ASE. (Why would you want to induce this anyway? ) By fluorescing it removes absorbed energy, which is what you do not want if this is in a cancer because you want to use this energy to destroy the cancer.  You could look up photodynamic therapy which uses visible light and oxygen to destroy cancers among other things.

Do you mean photon emission of some decay of ATP toward ADP + P? If so, what is the spectrum? I think this "laser causes dexcitation" can be separated from standard "laser causes excitation", hence such ASE could e.g. locally starve tissue, what could be safer than standard techniques, without ATP e.g. microtubules decay. Or inhibit some biochemical pathways, e.g. characteristic for pathogens. Or release energy from singlet oxygen, or other toxic molecules.

It will be the adenosine part that fluoresces so I would expect ATP and ADP to have similar fluorescence spectra. I do not see how ASE helps, the molecule decays in a few nanoseconds anyway. You do need to use its energy to cause some chemistry as in photodynamic therapy as I suggested.

ATP -> ADP + P releases energy, in life usually transferring it to a different molecule, or probably also to just thermal energy. The emission spectrum question is if this energy release could be as photon (of what energy?) - if so, we could try to speedup such ATP degradation with laser by ASE effect.

No. This bond breaking does not produce any luminescence, i.e. it is not a chemiluminescent reaction. You could certainly break up any molecule with an intense enough laser but it is very indiscriminate way of doing this. What is being tried now is to use a laser to observe the Raman spectrum of cancerous material   during surgery (assuming that this is sufficiently different to normal stuff) then to remove this by laser ablation.

So for a molecule being able to release energy, what are the rules to be able to release at least part of this energy through photon? In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiluminescence there is similar example releasing light from ATP energy with help of luciferin - why it is impossible without? Or maybe it just has a very low probability?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
